# Finding the 4th or nth Highest salary without using 'LIMIT' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

To get the 4th highest salary I have used this but this is not working, kindly help me with some other query in MySQL.

```
SELECT *
   FROM employee e1
   WHERE ( 4 ) = ( SELECT COUNT( e2.salary )
                   FROM employee e2
                   WHERE e2.salary >= e1.salary
                 )
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you not want to use `limit`? It would be the easiest way to implement this, as well as the most friendly towards a future developer (including your future self).

Comment: Yes 'LIMIT' is the most friendly but it  is used only in mysql

Answer (score 2):

Not terribly effective, but should work:

```
SET @i=0;
SET @N=4;
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *, (@i:=@i+1) As num
      FROM Employee
      WHERE @i <= @N
      ORDER BY salary) al
WHERE num = @N;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5a725/2)

Answer (score 0):

Six months ago the same question I found in [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/).

**Employee Table:**

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

Here's how I solved it :

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
SET @count := N;
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.


        SELECT tt.Salary
        FROM 

        (

                SELECT (@count := @count -1) AS c,t.Salary

                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT

                        Salary
                    FROM
                        Employee
                    GROUP BY Salary
                    ORDER BY
                        Salary DESC
                ) AS t
                WHERE @count >=1

        ) AS tt

        WHERE tt.c=0

  );
END
```

Here's the query extracted:

```
SET @count := N;
    SELECT tt.Salary
                FROM 

                (

                        SELECT (@count := @count -1) AS c,t.Salary

                        FROM 
                        (
                            SELECT

                                Salary
                            FROM
                                Employee
                            GROUP BY Salary
                            ORDER BY
                                Salary DESC
                        ) AS t
                        WHERE @count >=1

                ) AS tt

                WHERE tt.c=0
```

**EXPLANATION:**

1. getNthHighestSalary is a procedure which takes an integer as
   argument and returns the Nth highest salary.
2. first a variable count is set to N.
3. The inner most select query sorts the salary in descending order. So
   the highest salary is in the first row.
4. From this result set if you take N steps down and stop you  will get
   the Nth highest salary.
5. And that's the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query-

```
SELECT salary 
FROM employee AS t1 
WHERE 4 =  
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) 
FROM employee AS t2 
WHERE t1.salary<=t2.salary
) GROUP BY t1.salary;
```